# phpMyAdmin not working even i type correct credentials on Xampp

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I cannot access `phpMyAdmin` through `localhost/phpMyAdmin` on XAMPP.
I type `localhost/` and then, there is a link to phpmyadmin. There I type `username= root` and mysql password, it doesn't show error, but redirects me to same login page.

I changed the password in to mysql server password in

```
C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\config.inc.php
```

at line

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'abc123';
```

Before  phpmyadmin folder was not in htdocs, now I copied it to there also.

mysql server and apache are running fine.

But it is still not working and I still can't login.

Comment: just type root as username and leave the pass field blank..

Comment: Maybe you should reinstall. I am no expert on this but I didn't change any setting and it works. phpadmin folder is in xampp folder only, not in my htdocs folder.

Comment: i typed root and gave no password, but it still didn't work ..

Comment: what should i re install..? phpmyadmin or whole xampp package ?

Answer (score -1):

If i remove phpMyAdmin from htdocs folder ,
it says...

> It Object not found!
>
> The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.
>
> If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
>
> Error 404